# Page not found (404) on a Class-based views

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with my class bases views and i can't resolve it! i try to render a web page that show a detailed post. But when i try to route http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/ i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEbJG.png)
While when i try get http://127.0.0.1:8000/ is work perfectly fine.

I dont completely don't understand this!

my **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import PostListView, PostDetailView
from .models import Post
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='blog-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
]
```

my **view.py**

```
# pylint:disable=no-member
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from .models import Post


def home(request):
    context = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, {'posts': context})


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']


class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


def about(request):
    return render(request, 'blog/about.html', {'title': 'About'})
```

my **post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<article class="media content-section">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <img class="img-profile" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}" />
            <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ object.author }}</a>
            <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted | date:"d F, Y " }}</small>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
        <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
    </div>
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

thanks:)

Comment: which url you have tried?

Comment: what does 404 mean? have you looked up the httpstatuscode?
It basically says the page the user tried is not defined.
So you tried urls which are not defined by urls.py

Comment: Assuming your django is found on port 8000 default; if not check for the port;
Otherwise check the port your django is running.

For Ex. Im expecting localhost:8000/about/ to work but localhost:8000/about might not work? If I read this correctly. So post/<int:pk>/  goes to localhost:8000/post/5/ 
but localhost:8000/post/5 is an 404 page. The difference is the last forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per my analysis you are writing `post_detail.py` instead of `post_detail.html`

This is `.html` file but my mistake you wrote it `.py`. That's why it will try to find post_datail.html but it will can't able to find this file and throw `404 page not found error`

Comment: Sorry it s a html file i make a mistake in my post

Answer (score 0):

Nethermin it was a stupid mistakes!!

I just make a request on http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/4/ and it's work;

So post/1-3 just dont dont exit.

Sorry for my stupidity